# I am getting an error message to reinstall see below

Tags: jshint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P12eN.png)

Failed to load jshint library. Please install jshint in your workspace folder using 'npm install jshint' or globally using 'npm install -g jshint' and then press Retry.

Comment: Have you tried running `npm install jshint` ?